# How does Access-Control-Expose-Headers work?

Tags: node.js, express, https, get, cors

I understand it determines the headers the client can access from the server response, however, I am confused on exactly when this is applied. Does it determine the headers for *every* cross-origin request that is allowed by the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

To test this I setup a test site in express and put the following code in it:

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://www.google.com') // to be able to make a cross-origin request
    res.set('foo', 'bar') //custom header that should get filtered because i havent set the access-control-expose-headers header
    res.send('Hello world')
})
```

Based on my understanding of this, because I haven't set any special `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header in the response, the client should only be able to access `CORS-safelisted response headers` and therefore should not be able to see my `foo` header.

But when I'm at `https://www.google.com` (Which I allowed for CORS with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header) and send a `GET` request to my test site I see the `foo` header in the response just fine. Why is this? Could someone explain how this works or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be conflating [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) with [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers); those two headers have distinct purposes. `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` dictates which response headers (other than the so-called _CORS-safelisted response headers_) a script running in the context of the allowed origin can read from the response.

Comment: @jub0bs I don't think I'm confusing them,  what I don't get is that even though I haven't provided the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in the response i can read my custom header which isn't in the CORS-safelisted response headers.  (see my question)

Comment: Allow me to remain skeptical. Please add the script that allows you to read the header in question.

Comment: @jub0bs Alright, I understand now. It was because I was reading the headers from the Chrome Dev Tools and not actually from the fetch response itself. I posted an answer with more details.

Comment: Alright, that's what I suspected. Good that you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason I was receiving my custom header was that I was reading the response headers in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools. When I run this script:

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/')
  .then(r => {console.log(response.headers.get('foo'))})
```

It prints `null`. So the header is not actually accessible to the fetch request, only to the Dev Tools.